# using COM wrapper method to be able to run 32bit dll file on 64bit operating excel. (Can't register it through Command prompt)

Tags: c#, .net

``Hello, I have c# language running correctly and it builds the assigned DLL file,`your text\` but I keep getting this error from command prompt: RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registering COM Object on Windows 64-bit For Use In Excel-32 Bit Is Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070385/registering-com-object-on-windows-64-bit-for-use-in-excel-32-bit-is-failing)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.